# Liferay 7 in Glassfish 4.1.1

Tags: liferay-7

How do we setup Liferay 7 CE on Glassfish 4.1.1?

So far I've come across [this guide](https://dev.liferay.com/discover/deployment/-/knowledge_base/6-2/installing-liferay-on-glassfish-4) but it's for Liferay 6.2 and assumes that you want to use the .war file instead of starting with the sources and dependencies from the [additional files](https://www.liferay.com/downloads) on the liferay downloads page.